# Image not staying centered when resizing screen

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a card and I want to place an avatar in the middle of the card (photo 1), but when I make the screen smaller the avatar does not stay in the same position but it shifts to the right (photo 2). Can you help me?

photo 1
[Card with avatar in the middle on normal size screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIYjY.png)

photo 2
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTBLY.png)

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div mat-card-avatar fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <img mat-card-image src="{{current.avatar}}" class="circulo">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circulo{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `margin-left` from `.circulo` it should be always in the center

Comment: While removing the `margin-left` I get the avatar in the middle of the card, it is not in the center as I want it to be in photo 1.

Comment: can you please add screenshot

Comment: in the link of the picture number 1 you can see what I want to achieve.

Comment: No, Please  I need after you remove the margin-left

Comment: ok, in the link of photo 2 is the one after removing the margin-left

Comment: Trying setting `margin: auto` on the image or `text-align: center` on the outer div

Answer (score 0):

It's not staying centered because you gave `.circulo` a fixed `margin-left` value. Removing this margin should automatically center the image.

---

If that doesn't work you could use something like below:

```
.outerDiv {
    position: absolute;
}

.circulo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Note: The `.outerDiv` class should be added to the div-element around the image.

Comment: While removing the `margin-left` I get the avatar in the middle of the card, it is not in the center as I want it to be in photo 1.

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between middle and center? Do you mean that it has to be at the center and top-half of the card?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to say.

Comment: If you want it to be in the center but slightly to the top you could use `transform: translateY(-50%)` on the image. If it's not where you want it to be right away you can swap around the value until you find what you need. But it may be easier to add a `margin-bottom` to the image instead.

Comment: the avatar in the top half is already there, but I can't center it.